# Understanding explicit type casts in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT * 
FROM lookup_type 
WHERE type_group = 'enquiry' 
  AND type_sub_group = 'category' 
  AND type_attribute IN (SELECT prod_id 
                         FROM product 
                         WHERE prod_id IN (SELECT option_prod_id 
                                           FROM product_option 
                                           WHERE option_id IN (SELECT link_option_id 
                                                               FROM product_link 
                                                               WHERE link_member_id = '146')));
```

In the query above I would like to select a record in my lookup table. However I get the following error from my postgreSQL client.

> ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
>   LINE 1: ...uiry' and type_sub_group='category' and type_attr in(SELECT ...
>                                                                ^
>
> HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

The `type attr` is a `varchar` column and `prod_id` is a integer column.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this? An explanation into how to avoid this in the future would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you comparing apples to oranges? It doesn't really make sense that the same type of information is stored as a varchar in one table and as an integer in another table.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

PostgreSQL is *strongly typed* - every value has a defined type, and every function and operator is defined to work with particular types.

There is an operator for comparing two `VarChar` values, and *a different operator* for comparing two `Integer` values. Both happen to be spelled `=`, but they are separate entries in Postgres's system catalogue. Since there is no operator called `=` which takes a `VarChar` on one side and an `Integer` on the other, this explains the "operator does not exist" message.

In practice, the rule of thumb is that you need to make both sides of an `=` sign be the same type, so that they can be compared. This can be done using the standard SQL `CAST(value AS type)` function, which converts a value from one type to another.

In this case, you want the results from your inner `SELECT` to all be `VarChar`s so that they can be fed into the `IN` clause, so you can write:

```
... and type_attribute in (SELECT CAST(prod_id as VarChar) ...
```

An integer can always be cast to a string, because you can always write out a number using digits. If you know a string will only contain digits, you can also cast the other way, e.g. `CAST(type_attribute AS int)`.

Answer (score 5):

You are checking type_attribute which is a varchar field with an integer i.e prod_id. One thing you can, is to type cast prod_id to varchar in your sub query.

```
SELECT Cast(prod_id As varchar)
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have your query like this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM lookup_type 
    WHERE type_group = 'enquiry' 
        and type_sub_group='category' 
        and type_attribute in (
            SELECT prod_id 
            FROM product 
            WHERE prod_id in (
                SELECT option_prod_id 
                FROM product_option 
                WHERE option_id in (
                    SELECT link_option_id 
                    FROM product_link 
                    WHERE link_member_id = '146'
                    )
                )
            );
```

Lets start with the inner query:

```
                SELECT link_option_id 
                FROM product_link 
                WHERE link_member_id = '146'
```

If `link_option_id` is an `integer`, but `option_id`from the upper nest is a `varchar` types, you will have an issue. Thus you need to `cast` the result and have it like:

```
            SELECT cast(link_option_id,varchar) 
            FROM product_link 
            WHERE link_member_id = '146'
```

You get it. Same logic must be applied going up the nests.

Here is some more additional info on the CAST function (quick google search):
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, you can cast using the :: notation, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM lookup_type 
WHERE type_group = 'enquiry' 
 and type_sub_group='category' 
 and type_attribute in (SELECT prod_id::varchar 
                        FROM product 
                        WHERE prod_id in (SELECT option_prod_id 
                                          FROM product_option 
                                          WHERE option_id in (SELECT link_option_id 
                                                              FROM product_link 
                                                              WHERE link_member_id = '146')));
```

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: function concat("unknown", text, "unknown", "unknown", "unknown", character varying, "unknown") does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
1 statement failed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).